# Cannot echo longtext field using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, echo

I am running a php mysql query to pull data, and for part of the code I am trying to echo a longtext data field, shown here as the `$companystory` variable, using jquery:

```
    $quicksearch = "(SELECT * FROM companies WHERE 
    company='$itemclass')";
    $query = mysql_query($quicksearch) or die(mysql_error())
    while($companydetails=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $companystory = $companydetails['company_story'];
    echo "
    <script>
    // Replace paragraph with text from $companystory
    $('.details p').html('Here are details on the company: $companystory');
    </script>
    ";
    echo $companystory;}
```

Echoing the value the first time seems to break the code, however echoing it the second time displays it on the page, but not where I need it to display (Replacing the .details paragraph).

Also, removing the $companystory from the below line, like this:

```
$('.details p').html('Here are details on the company:');
```

Replaces the text, but obviously without the `$companystory` longtext.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because `$companydetails` is an array? Also you should either escape the jQuery selector `$`, since you're using double quotes for the PHP string, or use single quotes + concatenation ;)

Comment: can you show your output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are replacing the content of a HTML element and generating text that will be parsed as JavaScript you are better of using:

```
$companystory = htmlspecialchars($companydetails['company_story'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

This is better designed for HTML whereas mysql_real_escape_string() will only handle some characters such as a single ' and is really designed for MySQL queries and is also depreciated.

So it becomes:

```
$quicksearch = "(SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company='$itemclass')";
$query = mysql_query($quicksearch) or die(mysql_error())
while($companydetails=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $companystory = htmlspecialchars($companydetails['company_story'], ENT_QUOTES);
    echo "
    <script>
        // Replace paragraph with text from $companystory
        $('.details p').html('Here are details on the company: $companystory');
    </script>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some observations

- I presume that $companydetails[company_story] should be $companydetails['company_story']
- $companydetails is an array, however you are embedding it in a "string", did you mean $companystory?
- Inside a "string" you'll need to quote the $ of $(.details), as \$(.details)
- You are generating JS that executes jQuery to set the HTML of the same DOM Element over and over again with each result from the SQL query. You will only end up with the last result. This is not the way to build your HTML from a stylistic perspective and probably won't achieve what you are hoping to achieve, that is you should be building the HTML in PHP not building JS to execute so...
- What is it that you are trying to achieve, ignoring all the code above.

Comment: Hi Yorick, and thank you for your answer; This code is in an external php file, lets call it "external.php". What I have in external php are a bunch of functions that fill in bits of data or repetitive tasks. For example, this function only when ran, will fill in the company story, along with many other company details, on dynamically generated company pages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue with my first time using "mysql_real_escape_string" on the $companydetails['company_story'].

Here is the final working code:

```
$quicksearch = "(SELECT * FROM companies WHERE 
company='$itemclass')";
$query = mysql_query($quicksearch) or die(mysql_error())
while($companydetails=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$companystory = mysql_real_escape_string($companydetails['company_story']);
echo "
<script>
// Replace paragraph with text from $companystory
$('.details p').html('Here are details on the company: $companystory');
</script>
";}
```

This properly replaces the paragraph on the other page with the paragraph long of company details.

Yay! :-)